# Send unique value to $ get('page.asp?postId=' from links?

Tags: jquery

I want to send a unique value to a variable when I click on a link.

I want to send a unique value to the `postIdvariable` below:

```
function uploadphoto(){
    $.get('page.asp?postId=postIdvariable&id=' +
    response.id);
}
```

Im looping out the links from the database, that call the function so I have:

```
<a href="#" onClick="uploadphoto(); return false;">Upload photo 1</a>
<a href="#" onClick="uploadphoto(); return false;">Upload photo 2</a>
<a href="#" onClick="uploadphoto(); return false;">Upload photo 3</a>
```

So how can I send one value from photo link 1, another from photolink 2 etc?

Comment: I thought it was a royal servant thats been castrated...

Comment: Very mature guys! I guess you can speak fluent swedish also!

Comment: hehe i wish i did actually :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 1: Ouput your id as the argument to the function:

JS

```
function uploadphoto(id){
    $.get('page.asp?postId=postIdvariable&id='+id);
}
```

HTML

```
<a href="#" onClick="uploadphoto(1); return false;">Upload photo 1</a>
```

Option 2 (recommended): Use an html id or classname:

JS

```
// only need to call this once onDocumentReady and it attaches to all our links
// flagged with the css class upload-photo
$('a.upload-photo').click(function(e){
   var $a = $(this),
       id = $a.attr('id').split('upload-photo-').pop(); // parse the id number from the id attr

   $.get('page.asp?postId='+id+'&id='+response.id); // make json request

});
```

HTML

```
<a href="#" class="upload-photo" id="upload-photo-1">Upload photo 1</a>
```

Comment: Its the postvariable that needs the value, the id variable is seperate and it should be id='response.id.
So is this right then:
function uploadphoto(postIdvariable){
    $.get('page.asp?postId=' + postIdvariable + '&id='+response.id);
}
And in the link I can put a asp variable like this:
<a href="#" onClick="uploadphoto(<%=aspvariable%>); return false;">Upload photo 1</a>
Would this work?
Thanks, prodigitalson

Comment: Yes that would work. However, you generally dont want to go hardcoding js into HTML if you can avoid it. You are obviously already using jQuery so take advantage of it. Google for "Unobtrusive Javascript" for more info on why its better.

Comment: The first option requires you to code in the value of the return into the function.  With the second, it's easy enough to give each image an ID that is unique to them.  This way, you can have the jQuery grab the object being clicked on, find the ID, and fill in the get for you.  In my opinion, it's cleaner to look at.

Comment: even better actually would be to write the query string as the url to the link then jsut grab the href and append the `response.id`

Comment: ok, great I will test the second option first thing in the morning.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: By the way, I understand all but the .pop(), whats that?

Comment: its an array function `split` is going to split the string on the delimter supplied. which means in ths case we will have the number as an element in the array. `pop` jsut returns the lat element of the array. You could jsut as easily use `substr` or `substring` here... actually that would probably be more appropriate :-)

Comment: prodigitalson!
You seams to know your way around jquery, so I wonder if you could help me with another problem I have?
Of course Ill pay you for your time!
If you dont have time to solve the problem itself, maybe you could point me in the right direction?
If you have the time please send me an email and I will tell you the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, now I have tested the above and it works but I get one problem.
I ended up using the first option since I had to send 3 values to the function. I get the values from my mysql database and if one of the values is LONGTEXT in the db it doesnt send that value, but if it is VARCHAR it works? The "<%=rs("texten")%>" in the link is the LONGTEXT value that doesnt work: <a href="#" onClick="uploadPhoto(<%=rs("gallery_id")%>,'<%=rs("big_image")%>','<%=rs("texten")%>'); return false;">post to facebook</a>
Do I have to convert it somehow?

Comment: @Claes: just sent you a message on LinkedIn.

Comment: @Claes: Post a new question with some example values for your `rs` fields. Short answer is "yes" :-)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9499777/send-value-to-function-doesnt-work-if-it-is-longtext-in-database